ggplot2: `position_nudge` Respective of `linewidth`
I'm looking for a way to combine geom_segment() with geom_point() and define position such that it is always connected to linewidth.
Reprex
library(ggplot2)

# Sample data for geom_segment
segment_data <- data.frame(
  y = 1:5,
  x = as.POSIXct(c("2024-04-15 08:00:00", "2024-04-15 08:15:00", "2024-04-15 08:30:00", "2024-04-15 08:45:00", "2024-04-15 09:00:00")),
  xend = as.POSIXct(c("2024-04-15 09:00:00", "2024-04-15 09:15:00", "2024-04-15 09:30:00", "2024-04-15 09:45:00", "2024-04-15 10:00:00"))
)

# Sample data for geom_point
point_data <- data.frame(
  y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), # Adjusted y values for points
  x = as.POSIXct(c("2024-04-15 08:05:00", "2024-04-15 08:20:00", "2024-04-15 08:35:00", "2024-04-15 08:50:00", "2024-04-15 09:05:00"))
)

linewidth <- 2

ggplot() +
  geom_segment(segment_data, mapping = aes(x = x, xend = xend, y = y),
               linewidth = linewidth) + 
  geom_point(point_data, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y), 
             shape = 25, color = "black", fill = "red", size = 5,
             position = position_nudge(y = linewidth/25))

Output
This gives the desired plot, where points are essentially indicators along the segment lines:

In this example, linewidth is 2 and the nudge is linewidth/25, which is very arbitrary. I would have expected linewidth/2 would have been sufficient.
Problem
How can I define the y value of position_nudge() so this is the case regardless of the value of linewidth?
Thank you for your consideration.

I think the tricky thing here is that linewidth is parameterized in plot space (like pixels), while position_nudge is parameterized in coordinate space (like values of y), so you'll need something that connects those two in the context of your specific plot. Depending on the data range and the coordinate range and the plot resolution, each unit of y will cover different numbers of pixels.

@JonSpring, thanks for the insight and response. I knew it had something to do with this, but couldn't figure out the right terminology. Ideally I'd like to include this in a package I'm writing and to allow users to easily place marker indicators along their segments in a better way than "keep trying until it looks right," if it's possible.

Another approach could be to replace geom_segment with geom_rect, and geom_point(shape = 25) with geom_polygon, and then construct those based on a scaling constant you specify. Then you could plot in one go, but with more upfront faff.

TL;DR: It is as Jon Spring says, you'd require a mix of data-units and absolute units to get this right. This is the formula you need for shape = 25 offsets: 0.55 * unit(fontsize, "pt") + unit((lwd * .pt) / .stroke * 0.5, "pt").
Now to actual examples; first: let's setup in the same way:
library(ggplot2)

# Sample data for geom_segment
segment_data <- data.frame(
  y = 1:5,
  x = as.POSIXct(c("2024-04-15 08:00:00", "2024-04-15 08:15:00", "2024-04-15 08:30:00", "2024-04-15 08:45:00", "2024-04-15 09:00:00")),
  xend = as.POSIXct(c("2024-04-15 09:00:00", "2024-04-15 09:15:00", "2024-04-15 09:30:00", "2024-04-15 09:45:00", "2024-04-15 10:00:00"))
)

# Sample data for geom_point
point_data <- data.frame(
  y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), # Adjusted y values for points
  x = as.POSIXct(c("2024-04-15 08:05:00", "2024-04-15 08:20:00", "2024-04-15 08:35:00", "2024-04-15 08:50:00", "2024-04-15 09:05:00"))
)

linewidth <- 2

Then we'll make two plots. One that we'll use later, and one that includes the point layer.
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_segment(segment_data, mapping = aes(x = x, xend = xend, y = y),
               linewidth = linewidth, colour = "grey50")
p2 <- p + 
  geom_point(point_data, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y), 
             shape = 25, color = "black", fill = "red", size = 5)

From the last plot, we're going to extract the layer's graphical object (grob). From the grob, you can extract the graphical parameters you need for the calculation like the point's fontsize and the segment's lwd.
Now this formula I got through a bit of trial and error, but should be pretty consistent when linewidth and size vary. We just add this to the pre-existing y-coordinates of the points, and then plot it as a custom layer.
segments <- layer_grob(p2, i = 1)[[1]]
points   <- layer_grob(p2, i = 2)[[1]]

points$y <- points$y + 0.55 * unit(points$gp$fontsize, "pt") + 
  unit((segments$gp$lwd * .pt) / .stroke * 0.5, "pt")

p + annotation_custom(points)


A note of warning though, this does not work with any shape. You can see that circles float above the lines.
points$pch <- 21
p + annotation_custom(points)


Created on 2024-04-15 with reprex v2.1.0
To get this to work with other shapes, tweak the 0.55 in the formula to fit the new shape. Now because you mentioned you might be writing a package for this, I recommend just writing a geom extension that computes the size/fontsize and linewidth/lwd just like geom_segment() and geom_point() does, and then applies this offset. That way you prevent having to hack it with annotation_custom() and whatnot, as it can get gnarly with facets.

This is so informative and helpful! Thank you, I will look into the formula application to a new geom as you described. Appreciate the comprehensive response.

it's a little unclear to me from the ggplot2 text how to wrap both existing geoms into an extension to achieve this. For the package, users would need to be able to specify the segments and the points in separate function commands. I do see the benefit if we can offload the logic though, annotation_custom() is a bit limited in flexibility.
